# How to configure Application Cookie to trigger action on expire

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core, cookies, .net-core

In an MVC application that uses SAML(if it's relevant) , I have a cookie configured in startup. This is an identity cookie. When it expires, any web api that has authorize on it, will get an 401 because the user is no longer authorized. The cookie will remain there but will be expired. The thing is that I want to save some data from the cookie when it's created in the db, and when it expires, or a few second before it expires, I want to delete the info that I saved in the db from that cookie based on an Id that is in the cookie and , also, I want to log out the user.

I configured the cookie in the startup. I gave some options , including the ExpireTimeSpan. I I tried different variations of configure options but I got stuck.

```
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.Cookie.Name = "Test.Identity";
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                    options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Saml/LogOut");
                });
```

If this can be done with some custom made cookie, it's a good solution too.Something like a custom cookie like this:

```
        UserSession initiatedSession = await _userSessionService.InitiateSessionAsync(ssoResult.UserID);

        CookieOptions cookieOption = new CookieOptions();

        cookieOption.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(40);
        cookieOption.IsEssential = true;
        cookieOption.Secure = true;

        Response.Cookies.Append("SessionId", initiatedSession.SessionId[initiatedSession.SessionId.Count() - 1], cookieOption);
```

Instead of options.LogOutPath I tried with the LogInPath and I got the same result. The user is not logged out from the application.

This is the scenario that I expect: The user logs in the aplication, the cookie is created. I take the id from it and I save it in the db . After some time (the user is idle for 20 minutes) and my cookie has to expire. When it happens I take the id from it , delete what I saved in the db based on that id and I logged out the user.

Comment: Cookies are stored client-side, and the server has no real control over them. The server can *suggest* that a cookie be stored via the `Set-Cookie` response header, but it's up to the client (browser) to decide whether it wants to do that or not. Additionally, there's no mechanism to alter or delete a cookie; the server may only suggest a different new cookie be created instead (to overwrite the existing one). All of this requires that the client be an active participant: namely, that it makes an initial request. The server cannot do anything without the client initiating it.